# Directions between Two-point location in mapbox-gl - React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have two point i get it from database and i want to render a line From start point to end point

what I got is the Straight line in two points without consideration the routes and directions on the maps

So how can i handle it to take a look for routes and Directions on the map?

**here's what i got**

[image: one]

**here's what i expect**

[image: two]

here is my code

```
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {PermissionsAndroid, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class Mapbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.startPoint = [34.4999, 31.5542];
    this.finishedPoint = [34.4979, 31.5512];
    this.state = {
      center: [],
      // initialCoords: undefined,
      initialCoords: [-77.034084, 38.9],
      acceptedPermations: false,

      // Two point state
      route: {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: [
          {
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {},
            geometry: {
              type: 'LineString',
              coordinates: [
                this.startPoint, //point A "current" ~ From
                this.finishedPoint, //Point B ~ to
              ],
            },
            style: {
              fill: 'red',
              strokeWidth: '10',
              fillOpacity: 0.6,
            },
            paint: {
              'fill-color': '#088',
              'fill-opacity': 0.8,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };
    this.onRegionDidChange = this.onRegionDidChange.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const isGranted = await MapboxGL.requestAndroidLocationPermissions();
    this.setState({isGranted: isGranted});
    MapboxGL.setAccessToken(
      '....',
    );
  }

  async onRegionDidChange() {
    const center = await this._map.getCenter();
    this.setState({center}, () =>
      console.log('onRegionDidChange', this.state.center),
    );
  }

  renderCurrentPoint = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <MapboxGL.UserLocation
          renderMode="normal"
          visible={false}
          onUpdate={location => {
            const currentCoords = [
              location.coords.longitude,
              location.coords.latitude,
            ];
            // console.log(location); // current location is here
            this.setState({
              initialCoords: currentCoords,
            });
          }}
        />

        {/* current Provider location */}
        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
          selected={true}
          key="key1"
          id="id1"
          coordinate={this.startPoint}>
          <Icon name="ios-pin" size={45} color="#00f" />
          <MapboxGL.Callout title="My" />
        </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
        {/* user From DB location */}
        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
          selected={true}
          key="key2"
          id="id2"
          coordinate={this.finishedPoint}>
          <Icon name="ios-pin" size={45} color="#0f0" />
          <MapboxGL.Callout title="User" />
        </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
        <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id="line1" shape={this.state.route}>
          <MapboxGL.LineLayer
            id="linelayer1"
            style={{
              lineColor: 'red',
              lineWidth: 10,
              lineCap: 'round',
            }}
          />
        </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
        <MapboxGL.Camera
          zoomLevel={16}
          centerCoordinate={this.state.initialCoords}
          // centerCoordinate={[-5.803457464752711, 35.769940811797404]}
        />
      </>
    );
  };
  render() {
    if (!this.state.isGranted) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.page}>
        <MapboxGL.MapView
          styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Street}
          ref={c => (this._map = c)}
          onRegionDidChange={this.onRegionDidChange}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          style={styles.map}>
          {this.renderCurrentPoint()}
        </MapboxGL.MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  container: {
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    backgroundColor: 'tomato',
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878646/draw-a-line-between-two-markers-map-box-react-native

Comment: @Amalp i implement my code based on his answer but as u see in the first screenshot I got a vertical line sadly

Comment: no way. if you feed the shape property a array of co-ordinates it will not create a straight. make a sample project and try his answer one more time something is wrong with your code.

Comment: @Amalp Hmm, weird His answer works fine with u? I mean it makes a real direction as u see in the second screenshot?

Comment: @DevAS, it appears straight line, is because you only set 2 coordinates, start and end. Try to add more in-between coordinates in, this.state..route..features..geometry..coordinates..startPoint, anotherPoint1, anotherPoint2, endPoint. You got my idea?

Comment: Yes i got it, but how can i get this points ?

Comment: @DevAs Yes as adesst said you need an array of co-ordinates and you need an API for that in my case my backend team provided that for me. if you working alone check if there is any API provided by the mapbox.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Google Maps Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) where you will get encoded polyline and you can decode that encoded Polyline using following function

```js
decode(t, e) {
        for (
            var n,
            o,
            u = 0,
            l = 0,
            r = 0,
            d = [],
            h = 0,
            i = 0,
            a = null,
            c = Math.pow(10, e || 5);
            u < t.length;

        ) {
            (a = null), (h = 0), (i = 0);
            do (a = t.charCodeAt(u++) - 63), (i |= (31 & a) << h), (h += 5);
            while (a >= 32);
            (n = 1 & i ? ~(i >> 1) : i >> 1), (h = i = 0);
            do (a = t.charCodeAt(u++) - 63), (i |= (31 & a) << h), (h += 5);
            while (a >= 32);
            (o = 1 & i ? ~(i >> 1) : i >> 1),
                (l += n),
                (r += o),
                d.push([l / c, r / c]);
        }
        return (d = d.map(function (t) {
            return { latitude: t[0], longitude: t[1] };
        }));
    }
```

This Will return required data for polyline.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't use **Google maps** inside my project!

Comment: Yeah but the data is the same I guess and it is a rest API. Try it out. It might work for mapbox-gl as well.

Comment: I can't handle it for mapbox-gl sadly can u edit it to achieve ur idea?

Comment: sorry for disturbing you, have you find any solution with mapbox? i have same requirments in my project

Comment: It will work for Google Maps but I am not sure about Mapbox.